# PHP: How many of these lines don't work, static vs non-static access

Tags: php, static-variables

http://codepad.viper-7.com/ezvlkQ

So, I'm trying to figure out:

```
...?php

$object = new A();

class A 
{
  static public $foo = 'bar';
  function displayFoo()
  {
    echo $this->$foo;
  }
}

A::displayFoo();
A->displayFoo();
?>
```

About this, how many errors can you find?  Can you tell me what they are in real human terms?  I can't really interpret what is and what is not okay from the validator that codepad uses...

Comment: Step 1: run the code. `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in ... on line 15` Step 2: fix that error. Repeat.

Comment: Deceze, no it isn't homework.  Michael, I didn't solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ve updated your code here http://codepad.viper-7.com/UaUE4g

Error 1:

```
echo $this->$foo;
```

This should read:

```
echo self::$foo;
```

.. as it is static.

Error 2:

```
A::displayFoo();
```

The method is an instance method `::` is used for access to static methods.

Error 3:

```
A->displayFoo();
```

This is an error because `A` is undefined and if it was it should have read `$A`. This would be okay:

```
$object->displayFoo();
```

.. as $object is an instance of class A.

Next step, consult the manual on the topic *static*.

Comment: AW MAN, That was so cool.  You're awesome.  So legit.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  I kept wondering why my book said I could access static properties via static methods with object code.  I just didn't realize that by using a->, I wasn't actually using the object ($myObject).  So, static methods really can be accessed by object code, but they can't be accessed by class code?  Hmm....  I guess it still doesn't make sense.  I thought that static methods could be accessed by class or object code, but the book doesn't actually explicitly say that.  Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you should get another book :) -- Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where to start. Static methods belong to the class, normal methods belong to an object, an instantiation of that class. For example, you can have:

```
Class A {
   static public $foo = 'WOOHOOO';
   static function displayFoo() {
       echo self::$foo;
   }
}

echo A::displayFoo();
```

This works because you're calling the `displayFoo` method belonging to class `A`. Or you can do this:

```
Class A {
    public $foo = "WOOHOO";
    public function displayFoo() {
        echo $this->foo;
    }
}

$obj = new A();
$obj->displayFoo();
```

Now you're creating an object based on the class of `A`. That object can call its methods. But the *object* doesn't have static methods. If you were to declare the function static, it would not be available to `$obj`.

You can't do:

```
A->displayFoo()
```

at all, under any circumstances, ever. The `->` operator assumes an object, and `A` can't be an object because its not a variable.

Comment: Block 1: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ou8xep (works).  Block 2: http://codepad.viper-7.com/WYh7Xi (does not work).

Comment: block 2 works if you change $a to $obj.  So, it still answers the question, but there's a new error in the code.  Thank you.  I appreciate your answer. *thumbs up*

Answer (score 0):

You can read up on static class members in the manual here:

http://php.net/static

Pay close attention to the examples.